# How to use the webView feature in visual studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webview, windows-8.1

How can I use the webview Tool in C# in visual studio to create a windows 8.1 app (A simple web browser). I have tried these code and both of these don't work. I have worked with Visual Basic but am trying to move on to C#. I have tried these but none have worked in C#, please can someone help me out. Thanks.

Tried this, but didn't work

```
  private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Webview1.Navigate(http://www.bing.com);
    }
```

Also, tried this, which didn't work either

```
   private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          Webview1.Navigate(New Uri(http://www.bing.com));
        }
```

Am I doing somethig wrong or is this code not for Visual Studio C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this example out, it may give you some help in learning how it works: [Example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out a short way of working with Webview :)

If anyone else is having a hard time on how to use webview in C#, this might help

```
 WebView1.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://www.google.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a Uri(string) without ("") at the sides of string reference, the code has not problem but the syntax yes.